# Foreign key is not assigned using sequelize in 1:1 association

Tags: mysql, node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I have 3 models User, Question and Video

- A video belongs to one user and to also one question
- user has many questions, while a question has only 1 video
- I have got the association between user and video models done, however for video-question one not yet. The foreign keys are created successfully but on create method the questionId is not assigned.

Hers is a snap shot of how the models and the create function looks like.
Video Model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Video = sequelize.define('Video', {
    transcription: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT
    },
  });

  Video.associate = (models) => {
   Video.belongsTo (models.Question,
   {foreignKeyContraint : true , foreignKey: "questionId" });
  }

  Video.associate = (models) => {
    Video.belongsTo(models.User, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: 'userId'
    });
  }
return Video;};
```

**Question model:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
 var Question = sequelize.define('Question', {
  text: {
  type: DataTypes.TEXT,
  allowNull: false,
  }
});
Question.associate = (models) => {
 Question.belongsTo(models.Script, {
   onDelete: "CASCADE",
   foreignKey: 'scriptId'
 });
}
Question.associate = (models) => {
 Question.hasMany(models.Questionvariation,
 {
  foreignKey: 'questionId',
  as: 'questions',
 });
```

}return Question;};

**For the create function**

```
create(req, res) {
 return Video
  .create({
    userId: req.body.user_id,
    questionId: req.body.question_id,
    transcription: req.body.transcription
  })
  .then(video => 
    res.status(201).send(video))
  .catch(error => 
    res.status(400).send(error));
 }
```

The video is created however it neglects completely the existence of questionId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have solved it, the problem is that I have to add a hasOne association in Question model